# How do I combine the eigenfaces using Principal Components Analysis (PCA) and Neural network in the face recognition?

Tags: c#, java, face-detection, face-recognition

I am trying to perform facial recognition using neural network, I use Principal Components Analysis (PCA) to reduce the image's dimension. Now, I have the eigenfaces ( after using PCA ), but I don't know how to combine the eigenfaces and Input Neural Network.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit general (not a specific programming question yet), so I suggest you consider using research (see the reference, for example, http://bit.csc.lsu.edu/~jianhua/zhifeng-yun.pdf ) to isolate what you need to do next.  I hope this helps.